# How to use the \siunitx package within Python/matplotlib?

Tags: siunitx, python, matplotlib

I'm writing a LaTeX document and I include some `matplotlib` plots in it, in `.pgf` format with `\include{file.pgf}`. It has advantages over exporting the `matplotlib` plot to `.pdf` or `.eps` formats in that the fonts matches the one of my document and probably other advantages, but that is beside the main question.

In my LaTeX document I use the `siunitx` package, and I'd like to use it for the `matplotlib` plots too. For instance some axis might be the distance in meters, so I'd like to use `Distance (\si{\meter})` instead of `Distance (m)`.

From what I gathered from an extensive Google research, in the Python file `.py`, I came up with the following example:

```py
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('pgf')
mplparams = {"pgf.rcfonts": False}
mpl.rc('text', usetex=True)
mpl.rcParams.update(mplparams)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rc('text', usetex=True) 
if "siunitx" not in plt.rcParams["text.latex.preamble"]:
    plt.rcParams["text.latex.preamble"].append(r"\usepackage{siunitx}")

X = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Y = [-2, 7 , 3 , 8 , 7, 5]
plt.plot(X, Y)
plt.xlabel('Distance (\si{\meter})')
plt.savefig('file.pgf')
```

However it won't work and yields the error message:

```text
  File "(...)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_pgf.py", line 375, in get_width_height_descent
    raise ValueError(msg % (text, e.latex_output))

ValueError: Error processing 'Distance (\si{\meter})'
LaTeX Output:
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...12.000000}\selectfont Distance (\si 
                                              {\meter })
<*> ....000000}\selectfont Distance (\si{\meter})}

No pages of output.
Transcript written on texput.log.
```

If I replace `\si{\meter}` by `m`, it does work.

I am therefore unable to use the `siunitx` package within Python. How could I make it work?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is probably not the correct place to ask this, as the question is about Matplotlib and Python not about LaTeX, IMHO. I use `siunitx` in the following way:

```py
pgf_with_latex = {                      # setup matplotlib to use latex for output
    "pgf.texsystem": "pdflatex",        # change this if using xetex or lautex
    "text.usetex": True,                # use LaTeX to write all text
    "font.family": "serif",
    "font.serif": [],                   # blank entries should cause plots 
    "font.sans-serif": [],              # to inherit fonts from the document
    "font.monospace": [],
    "axes.labelsize": 10,               # LaTeX default is 10pt font.
    "font.size": 10,
    "legend.fontsize": 8,               # Make the legend/label fonts 
    "xtick.labelsize": 8,               # a little smaller
    "ytick.labelsize": 8,
    "figure.figsize": figsize(0.9),     # default fig size of 0.9 textwidth
    "pgf.preamble": "\n".join([ # plots will use this preamble
        r"\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}",
        r"\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}",
        r"\usepackage[detect-all,locale=DE]{siunitx}",
        ])
    }
mpl.rcParams.update(pgf_with_latex)
```

So you'd have to update the `pgf.preamble` to include `r"\usepackage{siunitx}"`.

Comment: I wouldn't like to change this in the rcParams. Is there any other way I can do this?

Comment: @MrT77 setting the `rcParams` this way only changes this for the current Python run; and you can make another call to the `rcParams` to undo the changes later, if that's an issue. You don't have to alter your global parameters. (and if you're using `.update` you don't have to include all these parameters to change the few values you actually want to change).

Comment: How can I make the call to undo? In my case, I wasn't using pgf, but I need to use siunitx for a single figure.

Comment: @MrT77 maybe it's best to ask a new question for this, as I'm pretty unsure what you really do and need. As for the "how to undo" part: Save the settings you change before changing them in another dictionary and restore from that afterwards.

Comment: I just uploaded this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73557104/error-in-using-siunitx-with-matplotlib-python . Thanks in advance.