# How to include a graph from python in latex text

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, python

How would I include a figure from `python` in LaTeX, in order to use the same font in the text and to adjut the size.

If you can include the code that would be great.

Sorry, if my question is a bit simple.

The last two lines

```
mpl.use("pgf")
mpl.rcParams.update(pgf_with_latex)
```

Are they ment to be in `python` code?

If so, what package need to be used with?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please consider explain your question a bit more, otherwise someone may tell you how to include pictures of snakes in your document. ;-)

Comment: Do you use `matplotlib`? If so there is a feature to save the results as a `.tikz` file. I'll write up an answer.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/391074/117050

Comment: Yes they are Python code, intended for `matplotlib`, so you probably need `import matplotlib as mpl`. You can also have a look at `matplotlib2tikz`. (That said, your question is not very clear, there are [many plotting libraries](https://wiki.python.org/moin/NumericAndScientific/Plotting) for Python available, and you give no hint as to what you're using.)

Answer (score 3):

If you use `matplotlib` you can use something like the following:

```
pgf_with_latex = {                      # setup matplotlib to use latex for output
    "pgf.texsystem": "pdflatex",        # change this if using xetex or lautex
    "text.usetex": True,                # use LaTeX to write all text
    "font.family": "serif",
    "font.serif": [],                   # blank entries should cause plots 
    "font.sans-serif": [],              # to inherit fonts from the document
    "font.monospace": [],
    "axes.labelsize": 10,
    "font.size": 10,
    "legend.fontsize": 8,               # Make the legend/label fonts 
    "xtick.labelsize": 8,               # a little smaller
    "ytick.labelsize": 8,
    "figure.figsize": [your-width,your-height],     # default fig size of 0.9 textwidth
    "pgf.preamble": [
        r"\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}",    # use utf8 input and T1 fonts 
        r"\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}",        # plots will be generated 
        ]                                   # using this preamble
    }
mpl.use("pgf")
mpl.rcParams.update(pgf_with_latex)
```

Change the `your-width` and `your-height` in the above to the desired dimensions in *inch*. To the preamble add anything you need to reproduce the look of your document (e.g. `r"\usepackage{lmodern}` if you use `lmodern`). After that you should be able to use `savefig('name.pdf')` to save the plot as a pdf and import it into LaTeX. If everything in the above was set correctly it should look like perfectly belonging to your document.

If you don't want to adapt your preamble here every time you can as well use `savefig(name.pgf)` and include the resulting file in your document via `\input`. This way you don't have to use your actual preamble in Python as the font is set by the TeX interpreter. But notice that this way compilation of your document takes a lot more time than if you include a pdf.

You can create a new figure with custom size with `plt.figure(figsize=[width,height])` (this way you don't have to update the `rcParams` with the correct size).