# Best matplotlitb to Tikz conversion tool

Tags: tikz-pgf, python

What are some good, well-maintained packages for converting matplotlib plots to Tikz files for inclusion in latex documents?

Comment: The built-in conversion of matplotlib.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/391074 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/426069

Answer (score 5):

`matplotlib` supports to export to PGF (the graphics language behind Ti*k*Z) or to directly built the plot via LaTeX and save it as a PDF.

To use this just use the following in your Python code:

```py
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
mpl.use("pgf")
# create your plot
plt.savefig("file.pgf") # save as PGF file which can be used in your document via `\input`
plt.savefig("file.pdf") # save as PDF created with LaTeX
```

You can customize the output of the PDF/PGF via `mpl.rcParams.update()`, which expects a dictionary as argument with which you can set several interesting parameters for the created PDF/PGF:

```py
{
    "pgf.texsystem":   "pdflatex", # or any other engine you want to use
    "text.usetex":     True,       # use TeX for all texts
    "font.family":     "serif",
    "font.serif":      [],         # empty entries should cause the usage of the document fonts
    "font.sans-serif": [],
    "font.monospace":  [],
    "font.size":       10,         # control font sizes of different elements
    "axes.labelsize":  10,
    "legend.fontsize": 9,
    "xtick.labelsize": 9,
    "ytick.labelsize": 9,
    "pgf.preamble": [              # specify additional preamble calls for LaTeX's run
        r"\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}",
        r"\usepackage{siunitx}",
    ],
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but the generated PGF file is huge (over 6 MB for a single picture)

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi then your data is huge, keep in mind that it stores every point on every curve. If that's the case for you, storing the data in a pixel based format can turn out to be smaller (so converting it to PNG, for instance).

Answer (score 4):

[`tikzplotlib`](https://github.com/nschloe/tikzplotlib) (formerly `matplotlib2tikz`) creates LaTeX code using the `pgfplots` package. It's available on Pypi, so it can be installed with `pip`.

Basically do

```py
import tikzplotlib
```

and then

```py
tikzplotlib.save('filename.tex')
```

after generating a figure. In your LaTeX-file add

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
```

to the preamble, and

```
\input{filename}
```

to add the figure.

The `tikzplotlib.save` function has multiple options for modifying the code, so have a look at its docstring.