# Nested pie chart

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-pie

I know I'm asking a lot. But by chance, is there someone who knows a package capable of drawing nested pie chart in Latex ? Something like this :

[image]

**PS** : It's more curiosity than real need, Python does it very well ;)

Comment: I don't know any package that could render this very fast, but it's mangable in Ti*k*Z, of course, with a bit of effort. I'm pretty sure that this type of question was already asked in the past.

Comment: If you are doing this in matplotlib, you could use a Latex-friendly backend... https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/508567/15036

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/159876/1952

Comment: Thanks ! Yeah I suppose it's possible to do it with Tikz, but very long ^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer below uses the [wheelchart](https://ctan.org/pkg/wheelchart) package, which I wrote.

A command `\WCtest` is defined of which the output depends on whether the percentage is larger than 1. This command is used in the keys `data` and `wheel data`.

Using the key `gap={\WCpercentage>1?0.03:0}`, a gap between slices is created if the percentage is larger than 1. Otherwise, no gap is created.

The legend is determined by the key `legend`. This is a `tabular` which is placed in a `\node`. The rows are determined by the key `legend row`. The result of all rows can be obtained with `\WClegend`.

A separate `\wheelchart` is used for each ring.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{text-family-to-math}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\sffamily
\def\WCtest#1#2{\pgfmathparse{\WCpercentage>1?"#1":"#2"}\pgfmathresult}
\pgfkeys{
  /wheelchart,
  data=\WCtest{}{\qty{\WCvarA}{\percent}},
  data style=gray,
  gap={\WCpercentage>1?0.03:0},
  gap radius=0.03,
  start angle=0,
  wheel data=\WCtest{\qty{\WCvarA}{\percent}}{},
  wheel data pos=0.5
}
\wheelchart[
  legend row={\tikz\fill[\WCvarB] (0,0) rectangle (0.3,0.3); & \WCvarC},
  legend={
    \node[anchor=east] at (-5,0) {%
      \begin{tabular}{rl}%
      \WClegend%
      \end{tabular}%
    };
  },
  middle=District AAL:\\\textcolor{gray}{Rs $12.9$ L},
  radius={1.5}{3},
  wheel data style=white
]{%
  43.1/Cerulean/Residential Buildings,
  24/Green/Economic Sectors,
  22.1/Red/Critical Buildings,
  10.8/gray/Transportation Infrastructure%
}
\wheelchart[
  radius={3}{4},
  wheel data style=gray
]{%
  20.9/Cerulean!50,
  16.2/Cerulean!30,
  6.02/Cerulean!10,
  9.59/Green!50,
  9.33/Green!30,
  5.11/Green!10,
  16.4/Red!50,
  5.7/Red!30,
  10.6/gray!50,
  0.221/gray!30%
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```